# Why any type can be assigned void* but I can not return void* for any type function?

Tags: c

Why can I make for example

```
void *j;
int *intpointer = j;
```

But I can not make

```
int ** function(){
    void **j;
    return j;
}
```

I understand that for example that `void* a = "any type"` because `void*` accepts any type,, but why for example any type like `int*` can be assigned a `void*` type? If it is `int*` it should be assigned `int*` type, why does it accept `void *` type? I am trying to understand this:

```
 void *j;
 int* a = j
```

Comment: Why do you think you can't do that? When I compile your function, the only complaint is that `j` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Elrisas It seems you are compiling your program as a C++ program.

Comment: @Vlad C++ holds both snippets invalid.

Comment: @anastaciu I know. But it seems he has a C++ program with the function.:)

Comment: @Barmar I have put why I am not understanding it

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I am working in c, not in c++

Comment: @Elrisas as Barmar pointed out and Vlad hinted to, both code snippets are valid C code, except for the fact that j is uninitialized, but that's not an error per se , it's unclear why you think one of them is invalid.

Comment: For example why int* = void *? If  an int* can be only assigned int* type?

Comment: @Elrisas In this case your statement is entirely wrong.

Comment: And if that is possible, why if a function returns int* why it can not return void*

Comment: I guess that you use visual studio and compile it using C++ compiler. Am I right?

Comment: @Elrisas Where did you put that? What is the exact error you're getting when you try to compile that code?

Comment: @Elrisas a function **can**  have `void*` return type, IDK where you're getting this info, but it's not good.

Comment: @anastaciu this is the warning I get: warning: returning ‘void **’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘int **’

Comment: @Elrisas what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc compiler

Comment: This is the code int **hola(){
    void **a;
    return a;
}

int main(){
hola();

    return 0;
}

Comment: @Elrisas A `void **` is a pointer to a `void *`. You can't convert a `void **` to an `int **`. The code you've shown in your question is completely different from your actual code. A `void *` can point to any object. A `void **` is a pointer to an object with a type `void *`.

Comment: @M.M Barmar is correct, it is my fault, I have reedited the code, the code of before was different. Sorry everyone and thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`void` is an incomplete type; it does not specify an integer type, a floating-point type, a structure type, or any other specific type. It is largely a placeholder.

`void *` is a pointer to `void`. By pointing to `void`, we leave it open what a pointer points to. So a `void *` could be an address that was derived from an `int`, from structure, or from any other object type.

So `void *` is not an incomplete type. It is some sort of pointer type.

When a `void *` is assigned to an `int *`, the C standard says an implicit conversion is done, because a `void *` could be pointing to an `int`.

Note that `void *` and `int *` are significantly different types. `void *` could be pointing to any object type, but `int *` should point to an `int`. The C standard even allows a `void *` and an `int *` to have different sizes.

In turn, this means that pointing to a `void *` and pointing to an `int *` are different. So, when a `void **` is assigned to an `int *`, this violates a constraint in the C standard. The `void **` should be pointing to a `void *`. The `void **` should not be pointing to an `int *`.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

In C the `void *` is indeed the any type. So when you assign a `void*` to an `int*` then the compiler assumes you know what you are doing. Switching pointers to void and back happens quite a lot in generic programming or every time you `malloc()` or `free()` and C programmers are lazy. They don't want to cast that case every time.

Note: A frequent pattern for this is that an `int*` gets passed to a function accepting a `void*` and then passed to a callback that casts it back to `int *` because it knows that it originally was an `int*`. Similar for generic storage containers. You put in an `int*` by changing it to `void*` so when you get it back out you change it back to `int*`.

Note: it is important that you only assign a `void*` to `int*` when you know it is pointing at an int, i.e. it was previously changed from `int*` to `void*`. Otherwise you enter undefined behavior territory.

Even for other pointer types C assumes you know what you are doing and it is only a warning:

```
<source>:2:12: warning: returning 'short int *' from a function with incompatible return type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

In those case the compiler (gcc here) wants you to explicitly cast the pointer before returning to signal that this was intentional. Because it is very rare that this actually makes sense.

If you get errors for any of this then you are likely trying to compile the source as C++ and not C.

Comment: So why if I can make int* a = void * b; I can not make int*a fun() { return void *b}?

Comment: But you can. Your example even compiles. The compiler warns about `j` being uninitialized but that's only a warning. At least in C. If you are getting an error then you are probably compiling as C++.

Comment: This answer can be significantly improved by comparing and contrasting C and C++: OP is clearly trying to compile using C++ and not C.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow No, also the compile warns me abaout incompatible type, should be int* but actual is void*

Comment: @Dúthomhasyou are wrong, I am using and compiling c, not c++

Comment: @Elrisas you might think that you compile as C but actually, you are not.

Comment: @Elrisas: Multiple people have compiled your code without getting any compiler message about the return type. [Compiling it does yield a message about `j` being uninitialized.](https://godbolt.org/z/o16djdazn) If you are getting a message about the return type, then you have something else going on. You may be compiling some source code other than you think you are compiling, or you have additional source code in the file other than what you have shown in this question, or something else. It is up to you to provide an example that demonstrates the problem so that other people can see it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I get this warning: warning: returning ‘void **’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘int **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]. 
    7 |     return a;                                                                                                              int **hola(){
    void **a;
    return a;
}

int main(){
hola();

    return 0;
}

Comment: @Elrisas: `int **` is not `int *` and `void **` is not `void *`. You have been showing wrong code all this time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have reedited it. I thought that it would give the same warning for one pointer also. Sorry for that, so why in int ** can not be done but in int* yes?

Comment: @elrisas: that's a completely different question from the 9ne you originally asked. So I think you owe a sincere apology to a number of people who were honestly trying to help you, both for wasting their time and for doubting the validity of what they were telling you.

Comment: @rici you are absolutely right, I am so sorry for everyone, I am new in c and I thought * would return similar warning than **.  Sorry, I deserve to be banned

Comment: You do not deserve to be banned. Just learn from your errors. This is the core attribute of all programmers -- the ability to learn, even when you've made a fool of yourself on the internet. We've all done that.